# Login With Facebook Android App

Tags: java, android, xml, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement login with Facebook on my Android app. I am using the following tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-app--cms-23837. I have no errors in the code but when I try to access the activity where the login with Facebook button is located I get a run time error. It cannot load the activity.

**Logcat**

```
04-06 14:57:05.024 8470-8470/com.example.martin.ivebeenthere E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                                   at com.example.martin.ivebeenthere.Login.onCreate(Login.java:34)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                Caused by: null
                                                                                   at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:99)
                                                                                   at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getCallbackRequestCodeOffset(FacebookSdk.java:735)
                                                                                   at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl$RequestCodeOffset.toRequestCode(CallbackManagerImpl.java:109)
                                                                                   at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<clinit>(LoginButton.java:58)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                                   at com.example.martin.ivebeenthere.Login.onCreate(Login.java:34) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Login.java**

```
package com.example.martin.ivebeenthere;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.ServiceFilterResponse;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.TableOperationCallback;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView info;
    private LoginButton loginButton;

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                info.setText(
                        "User ID: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                                + "\n" +
                                "Auth Token: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                );
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClickbtnFeed(View view)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Feed.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.martin.ivebeenthere">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.splash.CLEARSCREEN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Map"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" />
        <activity android:name=".Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Feed"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_feed"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CheckinInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_checkin_info"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Account"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_account"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".EditAccount"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_account"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Checkin"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_checkin"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.martin.ivebeenthere.Login">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_login" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.martin.ivebeenthere.Login"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="276dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClickbtnFeed"/>

    <!--<Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login With Facebook"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:background="#3b5998"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />-->

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update with below code.

**activity_login.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        facebook:confirm_logout="false"
        facebook:fetch_user_info="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Login.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback;

public class Login extends FragmentActivity {

    private LoginButton loginBtn;
    private TextView username;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        loginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
        loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                if (user != null) {
                    username.setText("You are currently logged in as " + user.getName());
                } else {
                    username.setText("You are not logged in.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                Log.d("Login", "Facebook session opened.");
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                Log.d("Login", "Facebook session closed.");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.martin.ivebeenthere"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/APP_ID" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: There are errors in my Login.java. All the facebook imports are in red and everything associated with them are also red. Says cannot resolve symbol on all of the errors.

Comment: add facebooksdk then after try https://www.dropbox.com/s/xd02gwvofn0f8cs/FacebookSDK.rar?dl=0